# Crash when closing window in a MacOS application?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, segmentation-fault

I am attempting to create a functional MacOS application but with absolutely no `xib` or `storyboard` file just to see how it is done.

In the `AppDelegate.m` I create and show a window and set the application to terminate after last window closed:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@implementation AppDelegate
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)Notification {
    NSWindow *const Window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:(NSRect){.size = {800, 512}} styleMask:NSWindowStyleMaskTitled|NSWindowStyleMaskClosable|NSWindowStyleMaskMiniaturizable|NSWindowStyleMaskResizable backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:YES];
    [Window center];
    [Window makeKeyAndOrderFront:Window];
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
}
- (BOOL)applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:(NSApplication *)Sender {
    return YES;
}
@end
```

`AppDelegate.h`:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject<NSApplicationDelegate>
@end
```

In the `Main.m` file is the following:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
int main(void) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        [NSApplication sharedApplication].delegate = (AppDelegate *){[[AppDelegate alloc] init]}; // I also tried using setDelegate to no avail
        [NSApp run];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

A window is created, but the issue is that when I close the window, the app crashes, showing an `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20)` at the `[NSApp run]` line in `Main.m`. Somehow the application does not terminate properly and crashes instead. Clearly I am missing something but the question is what?

***Edit:*** I noticed an odd occurance which is that the crash only occurs when ARC (**A**utomatic **R**eference **C**ounting) is **enabled**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the window is automatically released (and thus deallocated) upon closure. This, combined with the automatic reference counting, presumably creates a sort of double free error. To solve this problem without disabling ARC or disabling `releaseWhenClosed`, `Window` is made a global or instance variable. Doing so will prevent ARC from releasing the window after already having been released by being closed.

```
NSWindow *Window;
// ...
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)Notification {
    Window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:(NSRect){.size = {800, 512}} styleMask:NSWindowStyleMaskTitled|NSWindowStyleMaskClosable|NSWindowStyleMaskMiniaturizable|NSWindowStyleMaskResizable backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:YES];
    [Window center];
    [Window makeKeyAndOrderFront:Window];
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
}
```

Comment: When is the window deallocated? Do you keep a reference to a deallocated window?

Comment: @Willeke The window should be deallocated as soon as it is closed, as it will not be needed again. Keeping a reference to it keeps ARC from deallocating it again.

Comment: Your solution is working. but I -think- you did it the wrong way before and after your fix.
the "right" way, is  you need add  :
@property NSWindow * window; (this is the same as "@property (strong, nonatomic) NSWindow * window;"), then : self.window = [NSWindow alloc] ... and NOW the ARC will release the window AFTER you tell ARC to keep it. +1, -1 = 0 . in your cases, i'm not exactly what ARC is doing OR what the X button is doing, but it mess things up :)